# Postgres unique contraint ignores null values but Rails passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a unique index in my postgres DB within a table `participations` like this

```
"participation_uniqueness" UNIQUE, btree (event_id, firstname, lastname, email)
```

That's working great except that if one of the fields is nil, its basically getting ignored:

> event_id | firstname | lastname | email
>   
> 1982 | John | Doe | john@doe.de
>   
> 1982 | Hans | Doe | john@doe.de
>   
> 1982 | null | null | john@doe.de
>   
> 1982 | null | null | john@doe.de

I want the uniqueness constraint also to apply if a value is null, so the last record in the example table above should NOT be possible because its against the unique constraint.

In Rails I could simply add this as a validation method to my model

`validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: [:event_id, :firstname, :lastname]`

I am wondering why this validation is considering `NULL` for uniqueness checks but SQL does not?

Researching this topic I understand that it is SQL standard as `NULL` is intepreted as "missing information" and you cannot compare missing information to each other.

However from a logical point of view this makes no sense to me. I want DB inserts in this case to fail. How can I reach that without implementing dirty workarounds posted here for example
https://www.pgrs.net/2008/01/11/postgresql-allows-duplicate-nulls-in-unique-columns/

Comment: `However from a logical point of view this makes no sense to me` Why should only one person be allowed to have no name? Should a person be allowd to *exist* without a name? If the answer is "Yes" , it should be "yes" for *every* person! (ergo: you data definition/model does not match reality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values) using partial indexes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ab_c_null_idx ON my_table (a, b) WHERE c IS NULL;
```

Rails behaves differently because it does a whole bunch more in the [uniqueness validator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/883b2a8ceef5dc23cfb6ea60a616c93c3dbc0fd1/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb). It isn't just running a query.

Comment: Yep, that is nasty business @DonMB - might be worth jumping on postgres channel on irc. I'd hope there was a better solution, but I can't see it. You also have to take into account querying and such, and ensuring you actually hit the indexes.